# how to add counter to a class name in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <!--javascript-->
    $('.balance'+i).attr({someattr....}); 
    //if thats correct OR 
       $('.balance'+i+'').attr({someattr....});
```

I was wondering how can i add a counter to a class name in jquery like the above

Comment: Did you *try*?  I don't see how the second version adds any value that the first version doesn't have.

Comment: Syntax error : attr is a method, not an object.

Comment: This question is poorly researched; you need to supply us with code you have tried and more details in question. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @xXDarioXx: Actually a method IS an object. So your statement is wrong. But what you've tried to say is right, it's that he's not using ``attr`` as an object or a method, it's just a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not make any difference. In the second example you just concatenate an empty string to your class string. So both results in the same string. The following statement is true: `'.balance'+i == '.balance'+i+''`.

Since you does not need the second concatenation I would suggest using the first option: `'.balance'+i`.

**Hint:** You have used `{}` instead of `()` (but I think you just made a typo), so your example results in a syntax error. Correct would be:
`$('.balance'+i).attr();`